# Why does MSVC produce C3668 error when overriding function with correct signature?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I am getting an error when trying to compile code that derives from `QAbstractItemModel` and overrides the `data` function despite matching the signature exactly.

The following code fails for me:

```
#include <QAbstractItemModel>

class A : public QAbstractItemModel 
{
        Q_OBJECT

public:
    A();

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override; 
};
```

with the following error:

```
C3668: 'A::data': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
```

This is only an issue when using MS Visual C++ 14.0 while the MinGW compiler I have works.

EDIT:

```
//  A.cpp

QVariant A::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    Q_UNUSED(role);

    return QVariant();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you omit `override`? Would the compiler let you create an `A` object? If not, what is the error message? (It's just an experiment)

Comment: If I omit `override` then, yes, it does work.

Comment: Does using default value` = Qt::DisplayRole` help ?

Comment: Good point but unfortunately the same error pops up even with the default.

Comment: Does `A::data` have an implementation?

Comment: If you return non covariant value as `void` instead of `QVariant` (with `override` removed), do you have error message about non covariant return type (you might have other unrelated errors with that kind of test change) ?

Comment: @scopchanov I have added the implementation

Comment: @Jarod42 I get no errors if I change to `void` return type.

Comment: So it seems that `QAbstractItemModel::data` doesn't exist with MSVC (so diagnostic is correct, but issue is elsewhere)... Check include PATH and `<QAbstractItemModel>` header.

Comment: It is very strange. QAbstractItemModel::data is (should be) pure virtual, but the evidence indicates that is not defined at all.

Comment: Working correctly in MSVC 15.8.1 with Qt 5.10.0... maybe the original Qt's header file was edited by mistake? (Qt's installation should be different for VC and MinGW, so maybe the problem is there)

Comment: @cbuchart Yes you were on the right track.  The header code was edited somehow - I'm unsure how.  I replaced the missing code and it now works.  If you provide an answer I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature you provide is correct. As Qt installations are different for both VC and MinGW, the problem may be due to an unwanted modification of QAbstractItemModel.h in the VC version (for example, you were debugging and unconsciously edited the header file).

Check the header hasn't been modified and if so, restore it from a backup or another installation (same version).